# Search a string in complete MS Access database

Tags: database, string, ms-access, search

I want to search a string in whole MS Access database. How can I do this?

Comment: is this an access-specific question, or are you accessing access with a programming language?

Comment: What is it that you are actually trying to do? That is, tell us what the problem is, not your proposed solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What you are looking for is called **full-text search**.

According to [this SO question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/399406/does-microsoft-access-have-full-text-search), MS Access does not have this capability.

Answer (score 0):

Add a reference to ADO; for each table create a command using "SELECT F1, F2 ... FROM Table" (F1, F2, ... are the char/text fields of Table); for each table get the corresponding recordset; loop over the recordset, using .GetString to get the values in one string; use Instr() (case sensitivity?) to check whether the string contains your needle (delimiter!).

But why on earth you want to do that?

Answer (score 0):

If you're talking about searching for the names of reports, queries, tables, modules, etc in your Access file, then try [SpeedFerret](http://www.moshannon.com/speedferret.html)

Comment: I've been a big fan of Speed Ferret in the past, but they really dropped the ball and have not updated the program since Access 2002 (!!!). It's a dead program, as far as I'm concerned.

Comment: I know, I keep checking their site periodically for updates :(  If I could just use it with SQL2005...  That program was awesome.  I still use it for older Access XP and SQL 2000 stuff, so from that perspective, it's still great.  Not sure why they wouldn't update it, everyone eventually mentions it, so there's definitely a market there for it.

Comment: It was vastly superior to any of the alternatives. Unfortunately, it's dead.