# How do I search attached files stored in a MS Access 2010 database?

Tags: search, ms-access-2010, attachment

How do I search in MS Access (ver 2010) for data in files attached to records?  If I do a "Find" and specify text I KNOW is in an attached txt file to a particular record, there are no hits.  While if I have the same data in a Text Field or Memo field, Access finds it.  I understood from one of the Access help screens I found that it is possible to search attachments from within Access, but I have not been able to do this yet.

BTW, I did try using the query tool and searching for text I knew was in the attachment, but it was not successful, although it did find the same text within a memo field in another record.

Thx,
jmb

Answer (score 3):

I'm fairly certain that there is no mechanism in Access to find records based on text *within* a file attachment. A bit of web searching found an earlier question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/q/399406/2144390) and the responses seem to agree that there isn't.

One reference from Microsoft [here](http://office.microsoft.com/en-ca/access-help/attach-files-and-graphics-to-the-records-in-your-database-HA010341505.aspx) says

> By using attachments, you open documents and other non-image files in their parent programs, so from within Access, you can search and edit those files.

but I think that statement could be misinterpreted. I believe what they meant to say was that

"...from within Access you can open an attachment in its parent program and then work on it as usual (e.g., edit it, search it, print it, and so on)."

Answer (score 0):

You can use file system object, open the file as string and search sequentially. That's as close as you'll get